# Extending a LinkItem with additional text property for editors

Tags: episerver, episerver-7

I have a huge problem following Its too good damn hard article by Anders Hattestad.Maybe I'm just stupid, but I simply don't know how to extend LinkItem in LinkItemCollection to display a simple textbox where the user can enter additional query when targeting a search page.The problem is that it's a solution already in production that needs to be modified to support this feature, so I need to use the existing LinkItemCollection for this as customer has already specified the links in there. Can this be done without messing up the data and HOW, pls? Adding a ContentArea insetad is not an option.

Thanks in advance
Miroslav Ostojic